# Magento 2 moving the sku on product page

Tags: magento2, xml

I'm trying to move the sku on the product page but no matter what i do it sits at the top when I would like it at the bottom:

[image: Sku]

XML:

```
<page layout="2columns-left" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>

    <move element="product.info.description" destination="sidebar.additional"/>
    <move element="product.attributes" destination="sidebar.additional" after="product.info.description"/>
    <move element="product.info.sku" destination="sidebar.additional" after="product.attributes" />
    <referenceBlock name="catalog.compare.sidebar" remove="true"/>
    <referenceBlock name="wishlist_sidebar" remove="true"/>
</body>

</page>
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try copying the template for the page to a custom theme template and moving the element on the theme template. The standard template should be in Vendor/Magento-Catalog/Product/View.phtml. Don't edit that one though, copy it to a custom theme.

Comment: Have you tried using `after="-"` ?

Comment: Nope that didn't work